# Compatibility issues between package `tkz-base`, `inputenc` and `babel`

Tags: input-encodings, tkz-base, babel-french

I would normally work with `[greek,russian,frenchb,english]{babel}` which requires `[utf]{inputenc}` and am getting problems with some of the `tkz-base` macros. The error messages are incoherent so I hope the MWE below will do the talking by uncommenting either one or the other of the `babel` invocations. Examples 3. and 4. are straight out of Alain Matthes' `tkz-base Manual`:

```
\documentclass{article}
% RN. 3 Oct 2017
%=======================
\usepackage{comment}
%
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\usepackage[greek,russian,frenchb,english]{babel}
%     OR even only:
%\usepackage[frenchb,english]{babel}
%
\usepackage{tkz-base}
\begin{document}
1.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDrawSegment[color=red,thick]({0,0},{2,1})
\end{tikzpicture}

2.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDrawSegments({0,0},{2,1} {0,1},{2,0})
\end{tikzpicture}

3.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\tkzInit[xmax=6,ymax=6]
\tkzGrid
\tkzSetUpPoint[shape = circle,color = red,size = 8,fill = red!30]
\tkzDefPoint(-1+1,-1+4){O}
\tkzDefPoint({3*ln(exp(1))},{exp(1)}){A}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/6)},{4*cos(FPpi/6)}){B}
\tkzDefPoint({4*sin(FPpi/3)},{4*cos(FPpi/3)}){B’}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\tkzDefPoint[shift={(1,3)}](45:4){A’}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(30:3){C’}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawPoints[color=blue](O,B,C)
\tkzDrawPoints[color=red,shape=cross out](B’,A,A’,C’)
\tkzLabelPoints(A,O,B,B’,A’,C,C’)
\end{tikzpicture}

4.\\
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
\begin{scope}[rotate=30]
\tkzDefPoint(2,3){A}
\begin{scope}[shift=(A)]
\tkzDefPoint(90:5){B}
\tkzDefPoint(30:5){C}
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\tkzDrawSegments[color=blue](A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzDrawPoints(A,B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](B,C)
\tkzLabelPoints[below](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tkz-base}`

Comment: @egreg Probably we should edit the possible dupe to give it a more useful name!

Comment: That's a good idea. Or maybe making a “canonical” answer for this problem, maybe also editing the question.

Comment: `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` after `\usepackage{tkz-base}` does indeed address part of my problem, but I now find that `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` causes the compilation to go into an endless loop for certain macros of `tkz-base` and will shortly raise this as a new question.